# how to replace Dot Net ErrObject with try catch

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I have migrated below line of code to Vb.net and i am replacing  On Error GoTo with try catch block. 
so in below code,  if there is any error then the statement will jump to ErrorHandler: label where it will compare dot net ErrObject.error with duplicate key . if there is any  duplicate key then, the line of code  will continue to execute next statement. How I can replace this with try catch ?

```
Const DUPLICATE_KEY = 457
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
'down below there lines of code

 ErrorHandler:
 'continue if it is a duplicate key
 If Err.Number = DUPLICATE_KEY Then    'Duplicate key
  Resume Next
 end if
```

Comment: We need to know more about what produced the error, so we can tell you what kind of exception to handle.

Comment: There is no 'Err' object equivalent - this is a case where you have to rip off the band-aid and re-code from scratch (VB6 is 20 years old now).

Comment: My suggestion is to use the chance to refactor this code, and change the logic to validate for duped keys instead of waiting for it to crash.

Comment: Exceptions have no continuation functionality, so you will need to give some thought to specific places where non-fatal errors might issue, and how you want to react to them.  Ideally, exceptions will only issue for bugs or for things that are impractical to test beforehand (e.g. things where there is a potential for an inherent race condition, as with existence of files).

Comment: are you using a dictionary?

Comment: Thanks all, I want to know is there any equivalent for Err.Number?

Comment: The equivalent to Err.Number would be in the exception object which is thrown. The specifics will depend on what type the exception is (and the other details which other comments have asked for already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add more details to DaveInCraz comment, here's two samples showing how you could migrate VB6 to VB.NET:

First, let's start with a VB6 sample. Basically it's a subroutine with an error handler dealing with several error types.

```
Sub aSubToMigrate
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
   ' Down below there lines of code
ErrorHandler:
    'continue if it is a duplicate key
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case ERROR_CODE_1:      
            ' Error 1 case processing
            ' [...]
        Case ERROR_CODE_2:
            ' Error 2 case processing
            ' [...]
        Case Else:
            ' Generic error case processing
    End Select
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Error management in VB.NET deals with Exception object throwing and `Try-Catch` blocks. You can process separately each type of error by writing a `Catch` block for a given error type, as below:

```
Sub aMigratedSub
    Try
        ' Down below there lines of code
    Catch ex As ExceptionType1
        ' Error 1 case processing
    Catch ex As ExceptionType2
        ' Error 2 case processing
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Generic error case processing (Exception is the root class)
    End Try
    ' Code executed after (no need of Resume Next so)
End Sub
```

Of course, don't expect to always find for each `Err.Number` an unique `Exception` class, it's not a bijective (one-to-one) relation.

[More informations about Try-Catch blocks in the official site of Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement).